# How long does it take for data in firebase collections to start exporting to BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I have installed a firebase extension "collections to bigquery" to export the data in my firebase collection to the BigQuery table. I have installed the extension an hour ago and I can still not see any data in the BigQuery. I am new to FireBase so can anyone tell me how long does it usually take until data finally starts showing up in BigQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore BigQuery extension will automatically sync future writes to a collection to BigQuery - if your database isn't actively being written to, it won't do anything just by installing it.

To bring existing documents into the BigQuery table, see [this guide](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md) that runs through how to run the import script.